# Thighs rubbing during running

Tags: running, thigh

Nowadays during running, I have noticed that my thighs have started to rub with each other which wasn't the case before. 
What can be the possible reason and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chafing thighs is usually a sign that you've gained some weight in that area of your body.

Unfortunately we can't target where we want to lose or gain fat, but the good news is, if you regulate your diet, you will be rid of this problem.

If you have *not* been gaining weight, it might be a change in posture. This isn't something we can help you with based on two sentences of background. In this case, you'd be better off seeking the help of a physical therapist.

Comment: As a short term fix he could apply something like bodyglide to prevent chafing.

Comment: Agreed, @User999999.